# Is there a way to disable the logs created by the pagefactory

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng, page-factory

Could someone please let me know if there is any way we can disable the logs generated by the page factory for Chrome and Firefox

I did try the below options for chrome and firefox and I had also turned off the Selenium logs.

```java
Selenium - java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.OFF);

Chrome - System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");

Firefox - System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE, "true");
                System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "/dev/null");
```

But inspite of that these logs are still getting displayed.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Please find below the code:

public class LoginPage {

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='txtUserName']")
WebElement textfield_UserName;
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='txtPassword']")
WebElement textfield_Password;
@FindBy(xpath = "//div/button[@id='btnSave']")
WebElement button_Login;


public LoginPage() {

    super();

}

public void loginPageDisplayed(String userName, String password) throws IOException {

    try {

        if (!status.equalsIgnoreCase("Failed")) {

            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
            BasePage.waitUntilElementIsVisible(label_LoginPage);

            BasePage.sendKeysToWebElement(textfield_UserName, userName);
            BasePage.sendKeysToWebElement(textfield_Password, password);

            BasePage.waitAndClickElement(button_Login);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Can you share some code regarding the PageFactory initiation? It does not print out things be default.

Comment: @JoãoFarias I have added my code.

Comment: I had put in my Base Page as System.out.println statement. That is why the locators were getting displayed.

Comment: Can you can answer your own questions and accept them as an answer. Unanswered questions keep getting bumped. So please try to either close the question or answer it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PageFactory does not print out selectors by default. So it is probably something you added yourself in the base class.

A good way to research this is to use [step-by-step debugging](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-stepping.htm) in your IDE. Set a breakpoint where you use the selector. Run the tests in debug-mode and from then use the step in option to see what code is being executed. Eventually you should run into a line of code that prints the selector.